# Business Schengen Visa with no invitation letter

Tags: schengen, business-travel

I am a Pakistani National living in the UK on a spouse visa of a British National. 
I work for a multinational company and will require to travel to Europe frequently to speak to the governmental regulatory bodies. 
My question is that my company does not have any other offices in Europe so an invitation letter will not be possible. Is there any other way I can apply for a Business Schengen as my traveling is going to be very unannounced and getting visas will be an issue with my job and traveling. 
Please advise me on the best possible solution.

Comment: Surely a multi-national company would have the expertise to advise you, albeit they don’t have a European presence?

Comment: @Traveller: Apparently the company does have a presence in the UK, which is in Europe.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Sorry, typo, should have been ‘another’ :-) I just wouldn’t imagine a multi-national company would expect its employees to organise business travel-related visas without any help.

Answer (score 0):

- Schengen C visa (short-stay) can be issued for single or multiple entries.
  Typically a first-time applicant will be issued a single-entry visa with a short validity period and duration of stay. After several visits without overstays or other incidents, they will get multiple-entry visa with a longer validity and a duration of 90/180, i.e. up to 90 days within any 180 days.
- The visa application will have to explain the **premise** for the first trip -- what are you doing in Schengen and why? For a business trip, it would be usual to name the business partners you are going to meet, and to get a confirmation from them. You can try to explain the premise of your trip without such a letter, but that's unusual. Are you going to a trade fair without interviews lined up? Then mention that.

So if your financial and personal situation is solid, and if you truly cannot predict the date of even the first business meeting, you might try to make enough successful tourist trips to get a multiple-entry visa (which can then be used for tourism or business).

More reasonable would be to fix the date of the first couple of business trips, until you get a multiple-entry visa. Surely your business partners will understand that you need some planning time to get a visa.

Comment: Most of this answer appears to ignore the OP's explanation: "... will require to travel to Europe frequently to speak to the governmental regulatory bodies."

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I'm suggesting a workaround, not a proper solution. *If* his finances and situation are good enough, getting a multiple-entry visa shouldn't be all that difficult for an UK resident.